Converse of bounds on the spectrum of a Toeplitz matrix
The following is from Robert M. Gray's review (https://ee.stanford.edu/~gray/toeplitz.pdf):

Lemma 4.1 Let $\tau_{n,k}$ be the eigenvalues of a Toeplitz matrix $T_n(f)$. If $T_n(f)$ is Hermitian, then
$$m_f \leq \tau_{n,k} \leq M_f.$$

Here it is assumed that the sequence of coefficients $t_k$ is absolutely summable, and $m_f$ and $M_f$ denote the essential infimum and supremum of the Fourier series $$f(\lambda) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} t_k e^{i k \lambda}.$$
My question is the following: is there converse of this statement (potentially under some additional conditions) that guarantees that if $T_n(f)$ has non-negative spectrum then the function $f(\lambda)$ is also non-negative on $\lambda \in [0, 2\pi]$?

If every eigenvalue of $T_n(f)$, for every $n$, is non-negative, then yes, $f$ is almost surely non-negative.
Let us check it by contradiction.
Consider (4.14) in Gray’s review:
$$ x^* T_n(f) x = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \left| \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x_k e^{i k \lambda}\right|^2 f(\lambda) d \lambda .  $$
If $f<0$ on a set of positive Lebesgue measure, then we can find a trigonometric polynomial $g(\lambda) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} x_k e^{i k \lambda}$ such that $\int_0^{2\pi} |g(\lambda)|^2 f(\lambda) d\lambda < 0$, meaning $x^* T_n(f) x < 0$. But then it means the minimal eigenvalue of $T_n(f)$ is negative, which gives our desired contradiction.
